# How can I set Div Height to be 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am going crazy trying to figure out how to make the `.footer` and the  `div .content` have `height:100%`.  I know how to make the `.footer` stick to the bottom but then my `div . content` doesn't reach the bottom page.  I know I can increase the min height on `div content` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Here is [my site](http://bravocreations.com/wp/)

This is what I am trying to do but having a hard time trying to make the center page and the footer go to the bottom of the page.

Link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK3oG.jpg)

CODE

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>  
    <div class="content">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="column_4"></div>
            <div class="column_5"></div>
            <div class="column_6"></div>
            <div class="column_7"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>      
    <div style="display:none">
    </div>
</body>

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 157%;
    color: #666666;
    padding:0;
}
.content {
    min-height: 0;
.header {
    min-height:300px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
.footer {
    min-height:300px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
    background-color:#9E959E;
}
```

What I currently have after your suggestions:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 157%;
    color: #666666;
    padding:0;

}
.content {
    min-height: 0;
    background-color: #9E959E;
    height: calc(100% - 50px); /* add this */ 
}

.footer {
    min-height: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#000000;
    clear: both;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

.header {
    min-height:300px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .header {
        min-height: 25px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .header {
        min-height: 25px;
    }
}



<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>  
    <div class="content">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="column_4"></div>
            <div class="column_5"></div>
            <div class="column_6"></div>
            <div class="column_7"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>      
    <div style="display:none">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your demo site is very confusing. first clear what exactly you want to fix where?

Comment: I'm willing to help, but I can't figure out what you're trying to explain. On your example site, I see a tiny footer at the bottom, and a div#content with 100% height. Isn't that what you want to achieve? Then you say _make the center page and the footer go to the bottom of the page_ and I don't get it. Make the center page to the bottom of the page?? Nothing is called "center page"... Anyway, you want to have a look at Flexbox, the layout hero, a native CSS3 property : http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/ and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
.footer {
min-height: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#000000;
clear: both;
}
```

instead of

```
.footer {
min-height: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#000000;
clear: both;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
```

This will put footer next to content
[link here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmpojt14/)